# variable that can be used by anywhere in C#

Tags: c#

Basically what I am trying to do is set the value of some variable that some method is returning and then use that var in multiple classes, methods. Let me explain with code.

I have one class like below

```
public class Data : Controller
{
  public void Get(ref string somevariable)
  {
       somevariable = consuming some api here

  }
}
```

Then I have two more classes that want to use the value set by the above method without calling that method twice:

```
public class Data2 : Controller
{
  public void Get2()
  {
    data.Get(ref string somevariable);
    Console.WriteLine(somevariable);
  }
}

public class Data3 : Controller
{
  public void Get3()
  {
   data.Get(ref string somevariable);
    Console.Writeline(somevariable);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to achieve the same?

Comment: That is called a global variable. It is considered an anti pattern, use it as little as possible. Is it an expensive API that produices the value? Your question is tyoo short and simple for a better advice.

Comment: Generally in this case, you should create a service (new class) that expose a method `public string get()` and consume your api.

This class will be shared with all Data classes by dependency injection for example .

Comment: If you don’t want to call the API twice then you should _cache_ the results. Using a global variable is a really bad idea

Comment: Using `ref` is *something* of a smell as well. Where I work we have to have a justifiable reason for using `ref` (at least for non-structs) especially in a scenario where a return value would work just as well, which this seems to be.

Comment: You're getting all these random answers because you're [describing your attempted solution without explaining the problem you're trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Please tell us why you “want to use the value set by the above method without calling that method twice” and why, since both `Data2` and `Data3` have a dependency on `Data`, they are two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not recomended, but the simplest way would be to use static method of some class:

```
static class CachedDataProvider
{
    private static string response = null;

    public static string GetData()
    {
        if (response == null)
        {
            // consuming some api here
            response = "example response data";
        }

        return response;
    }

    public static void Invalidate()
    {
        response = null;
    }
}
```

Then use it in your controllers:

```
public class Data : Controller
{
    public void Get(ref string somevariable)
    {
        somevariable = CachedDataProvider.GetData();
    }
}
```

Better approach is to use service injected to controllers by dependency injection. Then the provider wouldn't be static and need to be configured as shared instance (single instance per application run).

```
public class Data : Controller
{
    private CachedDataProvider dataProvider;

    public Data(CachedDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public void Get(ref string somevariable)
    {
        somevariable = this.dataProvider.GetData();
    }
}
```

In both cases, you need to solve parallel access to shared state (updating provider's data). For example, if your controllers means ASP.NET MVC, then each request is processed on different thread.

Comment: getting an error while using this approach "ArgumentException: Type must not be ByRef"

Comment: It is your code. Don't use ref for controller parameters. But it is not known, whar are you trying to accomplish. But it was not the question.

Comment: i am trying to consume api in main method and then parsing those in two different methods

Comment: Your solution seems to be heading in the right direction, but it is inherently not threadsafe, and as you have described, there is a high chance that the environment is multi threaded. Consider using Lazy<T> or at the least locking inside your data provider.